# Questions about the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(x) = \lceil 2x - 1 \rceil$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Can someone help me ?
I'm really confused with these questions 
I do not know how to get the inverse !
and I'm not sure how to prove it's one to one

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Z}$ where $f(x) = \lceil 2x - 1 \rceil$.(ceiling function)

i.  Is $f$ one-to-one? Explain.

ii. If $A = \{x \mid 1 \leq x \leq 4\}$, find $f(A)$.

iii.  If $B = \{3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$, find $f(B)$.

iv. If $C = \{-9, -8\}$, find $f^{-1}(C)$.

v.  If $D = \{0.4, 0.5, 0.6\}$, find $f^{-1}(D)$.

Comment: Please, copy-paste the problem into the text of the question.

Comment: "In mathematics, an *injective* function or [one-to-one function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) is a function that preserves distinctness: it never maps distinct elements of its domain to the same element of its codomain."

Comment: ok so how do I prove it on this function??

Comment: If you want to find $f^{-1}(-9)$, ask yourself for what values of $x$ it is the case that $f(x)=-9$.

Comment: Yes it is thank youuu

Comment: Nasenhaar so is it an interval ?? or just one number ??:(

Comment: For the first part, it's helpful to either plot the graph of $f$ or tabulate some values. You can see that, for example, both $f(0.5)$ and $f(0.7)$ are equal to $1$.

Comment: It is not an interval, but a set. You call it the preimage. So to find $f^{-1}(A)$, find $f^{-1}(x)$ for all $x \in A$

Comment: can you tell me how?? by example

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Of course you can't get the inverse of $f$: $f(x)=\lceil 2x-1\rceil$ does not define a one-to-one function. Actually, $f(x)=n$ means that 
$$n-1< 2x-1\le n\iff n<2x\le n+1\iff \frac n2<x\le \frac n2+\frac12,$$
so it's locally constant (and non-decreasing).

On the other hand, in the last question $f^{-1}(C)$ does not denote the image of $C$ by the inverse function of $f$, which does not exist, but the *inverse image* of $C$ by the function $f$, i.e.
$$f^{-1}(C)=\{x\in\mathbf R\mid f(x)\in C\,\},$$
and this one always exists (possibly empty).

Comment: so is this the  right for answer : the interval fo c is [-3.5,-4)??

Comment: Impossible, since $-4<-3.5$. B. T. W., I initially mistyped the ceiling function as a floor function. It's been fixed (the inequalities were correct). You should find $\;f^{-1}(C)=\Bigl(-\frac{11}2,-\frac92\Bigr]$, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: can you please explain how did you get this answer ???

Comment: -9/2 will not give -9 or -8 ??? we are getting the pre image here right??

Comment: @Vilot: I'm sorry, I had a sign error in the answer (for my excuse, I think it was late, and I didn't check…). I've fixed it, and the answer should be  $f^{-1}(C)=(4,5]$.

Comment: can you please explain how did you get this answer ??? I'm really confused :( and shouldnt be -5 and -4 ??

Comment: @violet: I just applied the formula in the answer, to solve $f(x)=8$ and $f(x)=9$. The former yields $4<x\le 4+\frac 12=\frac92$, the latter, $\frac 92<x\le \frac 92+\frac 12=5$, and finally, for $C$, I glued these answers. I don't understand how you obtain negative values.

Comment: it's in the Q the negative!! -9,-8

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I didn't  check this point. For these values, one obtains $\bigl(-\frac92, -4\bigr]\cup\bigl(-4,-\frac72\bigr]=\bigl(-\frac92,-\frac72\bigr]$.

Comment: thanks a lot , about last one (D) it should be the empty set right ??